# Find distinct elements from List<List<String>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, list, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to find the distinct elements in a nested list based on the values of the inner list.

Current list structure : the following image shows a table where each row is a list of string and the whole table is generated using the list of list of string

[image: Table]

```
var eachrow = new List<String>();
var allrow = new List<List<String>>();

//eachrow is populated from db. After a complete row is populated it is added to allrow

//Sample
//eachrow[0] = "no value"
//eachrow[1] = "67" and so on
//allrow[0] = {no value,67,89,0,0,0,67,34}
//allrow[1] = {no value,201,45,102,0,0,47,12} and so on
```

Now I want to eliminate the duplicate rows in the table. I am not looking for a solution in Javascript. the HTML table is generated only for display purpose for the question.

**What I have tried**

```
allrow = allrow.Distinct().ToList();
//Doesnt remove duplicates
```

Comment: You can make `Distinct` work with a custom `IEqualityComparer` for `List<T>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx) like this:

```
var result = allrow.GroupBy(c => String.Join(",", c))
                                .Select(c => c.First().ToList()).ToList();
```

Also you can implement an `EqualityComparer` class and use it in `Distinct` method of LINQ. But I think it would be more simple by using `GroupBy` for this purpose as I mentioned.

Comment: @AndriyHoren...Yes this should remove duplicate `List` in `List<List<string>>`. Just try it.

Comment: Right, because you will be selecting group

Answer (score 2):

Ok so here is similar solution to @S.Akbari and should help you to understand how LINQ-based solution actually works.

```
var rowMap = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach (var row in allrow)
{
    string key = string.Join(",", row);

    if (rowMap.ContainsKey(key) == false)
    {
        rowMap.Add(key, row);
    }
}

var result = rowMap.Values.ToList();
```